# Swagger/OpenApi Model Example Value

Tags: c#, .net, swagger

I am trying to insert my own values within my Swagger/OpenApi, currently in the Model Example Value I have the following values:

[image: Current situation]

The desired situation is as shown below :

[image]

I've looked into it and tried multiple methods to achive this, for example I tried adding XMLComments like this:

[image: first method]

However this does not work. Then I tried to use the MapType function which provides this functionality, I've done this with the following code:

```cs
c.MapType<Student>(() => new Schema()
                    {
                        example = new Student()
                        {
                            StudentName = "John Doe",
                            Age = 28
                        }
                    });
```

However, when I try it this way, I get the following result:
[image: Result]

Any way to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method I used and which resolved my issue was the following:

Within the Swagger configuration:

```cs
.EnableSwagger("/swagger", c=> {
    c.SchemaFilter<SwaggerExamples>();
})
```

and then within SwaggerExamples.cs :

```cs
using Swashbuckle.Swagger;

public class SwaggerExamples : ISchemaFilter 
{
   public void Apply(Schema schema, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, Type type)
        {
           if(type == typeof(Student))
               {
                   schema.example = new Student
                   {
                       StudentName = "John",
                       Age = 28
                   };
               }
        }
}
```

This resulted in the expected values shown in the image in my original question.

Answer (score 5):

Use NuGet Package `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters` as follow:

Add your default model (the default value which you intend to be shown in swagger) as follow:

```
public class StudentDtoDefault : IExamplesProvider<StudentDto>
{
   public StudentDto GetExamples()
    {
        return new StudentDto
        {
             StudentName = "John Doe",
             Age = 28
        };
    }
}
```

Note it is implementing `IExamplesProvider<StudentDto>` where `StudentDto` is the main model which I'm sending to the API controller.

And this is how we should apply it for our controller action:

```
[SwaggerRequestExample(typeof(StudentDto), typeof(StudentDtoDefault))]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Post([FromBody] StudentDto student)
{
    ...
}
```

For more information and example, please visit the [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/mattfrear/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters) of this project.

Comment: I think this is the way to go, however I can't seem to import the IExamplesProvider<> class from the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Examples. after inserting ```using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Examples``` I get the error "The non-generic type IExamplesProvider cannot be used with type arguments"

Comment: @schweppes0x Import `using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters;` for being able to inherit from `IExamplesProvider<T>` interface.

Comment: Yes but it seems my projects doesn't like it. I tried on another project and it works perfect.  However I will accept this answer as working!

Comment: Interfaces aren't inherited, they're implemented. Please don't mix up terminology

Comment: Is there any way to implement this within a MVC project ?